# No funciona removeCallbacks(Runnable) al cambiar de Activity

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo dos actividades, la primera contiene un botón que me envía a la segunda actividad y la segunda actividad contiene un botón que al presionarlo llama a un Toast cada cierto tiempo y al volver a presionar el botón cancela la ejecución del Toast, esto funciona correctamente. El problema llega cuando ejecuto nuevamente el Toast pero salgo de la actividad y al regresar para detener el Toast, este ya no se detiene aun que presione el botón. Si pueden ayudarme con algún consejo se los agradecería mucho.

Este es el código...

1er Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    binding.button2.setOnClickListener {
        startActivity(Intent(this, activity_2::class.java))
    }
}}
```

2da Activity

```
class activity_2 : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var binding: Activity2Binding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = Activity2Binding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    val mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    val runn = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            mainHandler.postDelayed(this, 3000L)
        }

    }

    binding.toastBtn.setOnClickListener {

        binding.toastBtn.isSelected = !binding.toastBtn.isSelected


        if(binding.toastBtn.isSelected){
            binding.toastBtn.text = "Stop"

            mainHandler.removeCallbacks(runn)
            mainHandler.postDelayed(runn, 3000L)
        }else{

            binding.toastBtn.text = "Start"
            mainHandler.removeCallbacks(runn)
        }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a lo que comentas:

> "El problema llega cuando ejecuto nuevamente el Toast pero salgo de la
> actividad y al regresar para detener el Toast, este ya no se detiene
> aun que presione el botón."

no vas a poder detener el despliegue del toast, ya que al entrar nuevamente a la `Activity`, se crea una nueva instancia del Handler y del Toast que no es el que originalmente creaste y tratas de evitar mostrar, incluso el contexto del toast es el de otra `Activity`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    ...
    ...
    val mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    val runn = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            mainHandler.postDelayed(this, 3000L)
        }

    }
    ...
    ...
```

La única solución es detener el `Toast` desde la misma `Activity` que lo genera.